# Custom BatchStatus enumeration

Tags: spring-batch

Is it possible to configure a custom batch status enumeration in Spring batch 3 instead of BatchStatus.
Currently this is very limited. For example after started we would like to have running, pausing, paused, auto-pause, auto-stop, manual-pause etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing the `BatchStatus` with the `ExitStatus`.  The `BatchStatus` is an enumeration of pre-defined statuses that the framework understands and uses.  Since the framework needs to be able to make decisions based on those statuses, they are a finite set of values that are not changeable.

The `ExitStatus` is a custom defined status that can be used for the conditions you're describing.  You can read more about the `ExitStatus` in the "BatchStatus vs ExitStatus" section of the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html